# Best way to create an empty map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I need to create an empty map.

```
if (fileParameters == null)
    fileParameters = (HashMap<String, String>) Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
```

The problem is that the above code produces this warning: 
**Type safety: Unchecked cast from Map to HashMap**

What is the best way to create this empty map?

Comment: What is your declared type for fileParameters?

Comment: You'll probably get a ClassCastException too.

Comment: fileParameters should be a Map and not a HashMap.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

**1)** If the Map can be immutable:

```
Collections.emptyMap()

// or, in some cases:
Collections.<String, String>emptyMap()
```

You'll have to use the latter sometimes when the compiler cannot automatically figure out what kind of Map is needed (this is called [*type inference*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)). For example, consider a method declared like this:

```
public void foobar(Map<String, String> map){ ... }
```

When passing the empty Map directly to it, you have to be explicit about the type:

```
foobar(Collections.emptyMap());                 // doesn't compile
foobar(Collections.<String, String>emptyMap()); // works fine
```

**2)** If you need to be able to modify the Map, then for example:

```
new HashMap<String, String>()
```

(as [tehblanx pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636126/best-way-to-create-an-empty-map-in-java/636134#636134))

---

**Addendum**: If your project uses [**Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava), you have the following alternatives:

**1)** Immutable map:

```
ImmutableMap.of()
// or:
ImmutableMap.<String, String>of()
```

Granted, no big benefits here compared to `Collections.emptyMap()`. [From the Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28%29):

> This map behaves and performs comparably to `Collections.emptyMap()`,
>   and is preferable mainly for consistency and maintainability of your
>   code.

**2)** Map that you can modify:

```
Maps.newHashMap()
// or:
Maps.<String, String>newHashMap()
```

[`Maps`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) contains similar factory methods for instantiating other types of maps as well, such as [`TreeMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newTreeMap%28%29) or [`LinkedHashMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newLinkedHashMap%28%29).

---

**Update (2018)**: On **Java 9** or newer, the shortest code for creating an immutable empty map is:

```
Map.of()
```

...using the new [convenience factory methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of--) from [JEP 269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269).

Comment: In most cases, type inference works (ie. map = Collections.emptyMap() works)

Comment: Yeah, true. I edited the answer to be a little more comprehensive.

Answer (score 22):

[Collections.emptyMap()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap())

Comment: The problem was that this map can only be applied to a Map object not a HashMap

Comment: You should (generally) avoid declaring objects of their specific types and use the interface (or abstract parent) instead.  Try to avoid "HashMap<String, String> foo;" and use "Map<String, String> foo;" instead

Answer (score 15):

[The emptyMap method of the Collections class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap%28%29).

Answer (score 9):

If you need an instance of HashMap, the best way is:

```
fileParameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Since Map is an interface, you need to pick some class that instantiates it if you want to create an empty instance. HashMap seems as good as any other - so just use that.

Answer (score 7):

Either `Collections.emptyMap()`, or if type inference doesn't work in your case,
`Collections.<String, String>emptyMap()`

Answer (score 3):

Since in many cases an empty map is used for null-safe design, you can utilize the `nullToEmpty` utility method:

```
class MapUtils {

  static <K,V> Map<K,V> nullToEmpty(Map<K,V> map) {
    if (map != null) {
      return map;
    } else {
       return Collections.<K,V>emptyMap(); // or guava ImmutableMap.of()
    }
  }

}
```

Similarly for sets:

```
class SetUtils {

  static <T> Set<T> nullToEmpty(Set<T> set) {
    if (set != null) {
      return set;
    } else {
      return Collections.<T>emptySet();
    }
  }

}
```

and lists:

```
class ListUtils {

  static <T> List<T> nullToEmpty(List<T> list) {
    if (list != null) {
      return list;
    } else {
      return Collections.<T>emptyList();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about :

[Map<String, String> s = Collections.emptyMap();](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap())

Comment: You won't be able to modify an empty map created that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`Collections<String, String>.emptyMap();`